# Wrap "Single Column" Table into Multiple Columns Based on Max Row Length

Tags: html, css

I want to wrap the columns in a table into a second set of column once my table hits a specific length.  For example I have this "single column" table with field names and values:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" >
    <tr height="50px">
        <td width="150">
            <strong>Field 1:</strong>
        </td>
        <td width="200">Data 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="50px">
        <td width="150">
            <strong>Field 2:</strong>
        </td>
        <td width="200">Data 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="50px">
        <td width="150">
            <strong>Field 3:</strong>
        </td>
        <td width="200">Data 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="50px">
        <td width="150">
            <strong>Field 4:</strong>
        </td>
        <td width="200">Data 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="50px">
        <td width="150">
            <strong>Field 5:</strong>
        </td>
        <td width="200">Data 5</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I would like a max number of three rows and make it wrap into multiple columns like so (without changing the underlying HTML as I've done here):

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" >
    <tr height="50px">
        <td width="150">
            <strong>Field 1:</strong>
        </td>
        <td width="200">Data 1</td>
        <td width="150">
            <strong>Field 4:</strong>
        </td>
        <td width="200">Data 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="50px">
        <td width="150">
            <strong>Field 2:</strong>
        </td>
        <td width="200">Data 2</td>
        <td width="150">
            <strong>Field 5:</strong>
        </td>
        <td width="200">Data 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="50px">
        <td width="150">
            <strong>Field 3:</strong>
        </td>
        <td width="200">Data 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

My preference would be to use CSS as my ability to use Javascript and Javascript libraries is limited on my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you would not use table elements if you are looking to manipulate HTML in different ways other than how a table should flow, but given you don't want to change the HTML, you could try something like this:

```
tr {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  height: auto;
}
```

You can see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f8jm4vgh/) that shows how it looks. You would need some kind of class or something to determine when its greater than 3 rows and specify that in the CSS. For example .greater3rows tr and have greater3rows as a class in your table.